How to deploy a Flask Application On Bluehost?
Is there a way to deploy my Flask application on Bluehost shared hosting? I have tried following the tutorials provided by Bluehost, but I keep encountering issues related to Apache configuration and Python environment setup. Additionally, I'm unable to install necessary packages or modify server settings due to shared hosting restrictions. Has anyone successfully deployed a Flask app on Bluehost shared hosting, or is there a recommended approach or workaround to make this possible? I would appreciate any guidance, resources, or step-by-step instructions from those who have faced and overcome similar challenges.
